# How to compile two java files in the same package

Tags: java, compilation

This is my code in one file:

```
package AI;

public class Class1 {
    public static void main1() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

And the other file:

```
package AI;

public class partsOfSpeech {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Class1 firstInstance = new Class1();
        firstInstance.main1();
    }
}
```

How do I compile these files, so that I don't get an error that says it can't find Class1?  And how do I run them once they are compiled?

Comment: are you using ide or command line

Comment: if you use command line to compile. for first compile Class1 then compile second class partsOfSpeech . but if you use IDE no problem is build automatically

Comment: No I did that and it still didn't work

Comment: When I try to compile partsofspeech, it says it cant find Class1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Go one directory above AI (e.g. `D:\Study\Examples\src`)

2) javac -d . AI/Class1.java

3) javac -d . AI/partsOfSpeech.java

4) java AI.partsOfSpeech

***output:***

**Hello**

Directory structure:

In my system, AI directory is under src directory.

Directory of D:\Study\Examples\src\AI

```
11/15/2015  11:06 PM    <DIR>          .
11/15/2015  11:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/15/2015  11:06 PM               390 Class1.class
11/15/2015  10:58 PM               118 Class1.java
11/15/2015  11:06 PM               333 partsOfSpeech.class
11/15/2015  10:59 PM               177 partsOfSpeech.java
               4 File(s)          1,018 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  236,298,690,560 bytes free

D:\Study\Examples\src>
```

Answer (score 1):

just open package AI in commend line and

```
D:\AI>javac partsOfSpeech.java Class1.java
```

both class compile---
For Run the class in Commend line

```
D:/>java AI.partsOfSpeech
```

your class run

Comment: No that didn't work it gave me: javac: file not found: AI/partsOfSpeech.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: Is still doesnt work.